# Reemplazar en cUrl

Tags: php, curl

**URL ACTUALIZADAS**

Hola quiero descargar un archivo externo y reemplazar algunos caracteres y guardar los datos en un archivo de mi servidor.

Aqui muestra como lo hace, lo que quiero hacer es usando cUrl, ya que el proveedor hosting nuevo no me permite usar estas funciones de aqui, pero cUrl si.

```
<?php

$file = file("http://exabytetv.info/sgeo.m3u");

// Reemplazando
$bodytag = str_replace(' url-tvg="atv"', "",$file);

$cadena_equipo = implode("", $bodytag);

$file = 'lista.m3u';

$current = file_get_contents($file);

$current = $cadena_equipo;

file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Aqui descargo un archivo, pero no se modifica.

```
<?php
ob_start();
    $url  = "http://exabytetv.info/sgeo.m3u";

    //El nombre del archivo donde se almacenara los datos descargados.
    $filePath = @fopen("lista.m3u", "w");

    //Inicializa Curl.
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Pasamos la url a donde debe ir.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $bodytag);
    //Si necesitamos el header del archivo, en este caso no.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    //Si necesitamos descargar el archivo.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //Lee el header y se mueve a la siguiente localización.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    //Cantidad de segundo de limite para conectarse.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    //Cantidad de segundos de limite para ejecutar curl. 0 significa indefinido.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    //Donde almacenaremos el archivo.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $filePath);
    //curl_exec ejecuta el script.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
    //Dejamos de utilizar el archivo creado.
    fclose($fd);
    if($result){ //funciono ?
         echo "Descarga correcta.";
    // header('Location: convertir-local.php');
     }
?>
```

Quiero descargar archivo externo, leerlo, reemplazar algunos caracteres y guardarlo. se agradece de antemano.

Comment: No puedo reproducir tu error, me da un error HTTP 404 Not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que tu error es que no estabas configurando adecuadamente la URL en `CURLOPT_URL`:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$url  = "http://hola.com/sgeo.m3u";

//Inicializa Curl.
$ch = curl_init();

//Pasamos la url a donde debe ir.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//Si necesitamos el header del archivo, en este caso no.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
//Si necesitamos descargar el archivo.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//Lee el header y se mueve a la siguiente localización.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
//Cantidad de segundo de limite para conectarse.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
//Cantidad de segundos de limite para ejecutar curl. 0 significa indefinido.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);

//curl_exec ejecuta el script.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result !== false) { //funciono ?
 echo "Descarga correcta.";
 $result = str_replace(' url-tvg="atv"', "",$result);
 file_put_contents("lista.m3u", $result);
}
```

Por cierto, si usas `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` no necesitas asignar un archivo de salida. La salida de `curl_exec()` será el contenido descargado y, por lo tanto, podrás usar `file_put_contents()` para guardarlo de manera sencilla.